# Error Zoom Out MKMapView

Tags: swift, mkmapview

This works fine ,but when I continually press the zoom out button it give me exception after some level. How can I prevent it ?

```
//MARK: MKMapView
extension MKMapView {

    // delta is the zoom factor
    // 2 will zoom out x2
    // .5 will zoom in by x2

    func setZoomByDelta(delta: Double, animated: Bool) {
        var _region = region
        var _span = region.span
        _span.latitudeDelta *= delta
        _span.longitudeDelta *= delta
        _region.span = _span

        setRegion(_region, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the Exception?

Comment: The Exception is Invalid Region Center

Comment: Where did the variable `region` come from? You didn't specify in your codes. Also, you can `NSLog` the `region.center` to prove that it's valid

Comment: Please post the `NSLog` results and specify where `region` come from.

Comment: I call this function when press zoom out. self.mapView.setZoomByDelta(2, animated: true), and exception is: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region <center:+4.12435007, -72.91625977 span:+263.28337480, +224.56343302>'